# Frequency Analysis in Python -Print letters with frequency rather than numbers with frequency

Tags: python, numbers, histogram, frequency-analysis

```
s=array1 #user inputs an array with text in it
n=len(s)
f=arange(0,26,1)
import collections
dict = collections.defaultdict(int)
for c in s:
    dict[c] += 1

for c in f:
    print  c,dict[c]/float(n)
```

In the output, c is in numbers rather then letters and I'm not sure how to convert it back to letters.

Also, is there any way to get the frequency/letters into arrays so it'd be possible to plot them in a histogram?

Comment: What is IntArrayToText called with? Is it a string?

Answer (score 4):

It should be pointed out that you aren't calling [map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) with the right type of arguments (thus the `TypeError`). It takes a single function and one or more iterables, to which the function is applied to. Your second argument is toChar[i] which would be a string. All iterables implement [`__iter__`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types). To illustrate:

```
>>> l, t = [], ()
>>> l.__iter__
<<< <method-wrapper '__iter__' of list object at 0x7ebcd6ac>
>>> t.__iter__
<<< <method-wrapper '__iter__' of tuple object at 0x7ef6102c>
```

[DTing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925442/frequency-analysis-in-python-print-letters-with-frequency-rather-than-numbers-wi/5925610#5925610) reminded me of [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = 'asdfbasdfezadfweradf'
>>> dict((k, float(v)/len(a)) for k,v in Counter(a).most_common())
<<<
{'a': 0.2,
 'b': 0.05,
 'd': 0.2,
 'e': 0.1,
 'f': 0.2,
 'r': 0.05,
 's': 0.1,
 'w': 0.05,
 'z': 0.05}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using python 2.7 or greater you can use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

**Python 2.7+**

```
>>> import collections
>>> s = "I want to count frequencies."
>>> counter = collections.Counter(s)
>>> counter
Counter({' ': 4, 'e': 3, 'n': 3, 't': 3, 'c': 2, 'o': 2, 'u': 2, 'a': 1, 'f': 1, 'I': 1,     'q': 1, 'i': 1, 's': 1, 'r': 1, 'w': 1, '.': 1})
>>> n = sum(counter.values()) * 1.0   # Convert to float so division returns float.
>>> n
28
>>> [(char, count / n) for char, count in counter.most_common()]
[(' ', 0.14285714285714285), ('e', 0.10714285714285714), ('n', 0.10714285714285714), ('t', 0.10714285714285714), ('c', 0.07142857142857142), ('o', 0.07142857142857142), ('u', 0.07142857142857142), ('a', 0.03571428571428571), ('f', 0.03571428571428571), ('I', 0.03571428571428571), ('q', 0.03571428571428571), ('i', 0.03571428571428571), ('s', 0.03571428571428571), ('r', 0.03571428571428571), ('w', 0.03571428571428571), ('.', 0.03571428571428571)]
```

**Python 3+**

```
>>> import collections
>>> s = "I want to count frequencies."
>>> counter = collections.Counter(s)
>>> counter
Counter({' ': 4, 'e': 3, 'n': 3, 't': 3, 'c': 2, 'o': 2, 'u': 2, 'a': 1, 'f': 1, 'I': 1,     'q': 1, 'i': 1, 's': 1, 'r': 1, 'w': 1, '.': 1})
>>> n = sum(counter.values())
>>> n
28
>>> [(char, count / n) for char, count in counter.most_common()]
[(' ', 0.14285714285714285), ('e', 0.10714285714285714), ('n', 0.10714285714285714), ('t', 0.10714285714285714), ('c', 0.07142857142857142), ('o', 0.07142857142857142), ('u', 0.07142857142857142), ('a', 0.03571428571428571), ('f', 0.03571428571428571), ('I', 0.03571428571428571), ('q', 0.03571428571428571), ('i', 0.03571428571428571), ('s', 0.03571428571428571), ('r', 0.03571428571428571), ('w', 0.03571428571428571), ('.', 0.03571428571428571)]
```

This will also return the (char, frequency) tuple in descending order of frequency.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a number to the letter it represents, simply use the built-in `chr`:

```
>>> chr(98)
'b'
>>> chr(66)
'B'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = "asdfbasdfezadfweradf"
>>> import collections
>>> counts = collections.defaultdict(int)
>>> for letter in a:
...     counts[letter]+=1
... 
>>> print counts
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'a': 4, 'b': 1, 'e': 2, 'd': 4, 'f': 4, 's': 2, 'r': 1, 'w': 1, 'z': 1})
>>> hist = dict( (k, float(v)/len(a)) for k,v in counts.iteritems())
>>> print hist
{'a': 0.2, 'b': 0.05, 'e': 0.1, 'd': 0.2, 'f': 0.2, 's': 0.1, 'r': 0.05, 'w': 0.05, 'z': 0.05}
```

Comment: Nice! Made me think of `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 0):

To convert frequency/letters into arrays:

```
hisArray = [dict[c]/float(n) for c in f]
```